# Azure Function App deployment is not showing in Azure Portal

Tags: azure-functions

I've used the default Function template from Microsoft for a HTTP Trigger.
I've done this in Visual Studio Code and deployed it to a Function App Site.

1. The function doesn't show up in the Azure Portal.
2. When I deploy there was a previous function as a Docker image Visual Studio says it will overwrite, but the Azure Portal still shows that the Docker image is deployed.
3. Deploying from Visual Studio doesn't throw up any problems, but does give a warning about the Function version being V4 when Visual Studio is targeting V3. When the version is changed in the portal the warning goes away, but the function still doesn't deploy.

Has anyone got any advice or good working instructional examples for Azure Functions?

Comment: Could you provide the template you followed or that Microsoft documentation link containing that template??

Comment: Hi,

I've tried both the Python and Java ones.
Python link below
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cfunctionsv2&pivots=programming-language-python

Comment: Yes, @DataDemon, I reproduced your issue, Created Python Azure Function (HTTP Trigger, Blob Trigger), and published it to Azure Function App Created with the Docker Container Publish Option and I see there are no functions in it after publishing! Let me find the resolution to it!

Comment: We have a similar problem, will check the logs on Kudu and get back to you.

Comment: @HariKrishna, any luck, facing a similar issue

Comment: @Romesh, Will check and let you know in few hours